# Hermite interpolation of even degree

Tags: numerical-methods

Using Hermite interpolation determine the fourth degree polynomial $p(x)$ for which
\begin{equation}
        p(0) = p'(0) = 0, \quad p(1) = p'(1) = 1, \quad p(2) = 1
    \end{equation}

I can only seem to find content on how to apply Hermite interpolation to data points with odd degree polynomial. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So $p(x)\equiv 0\pmod{x^2}$, $p(x)\equiv 1+x\pmod{(x-1)^2}$ and $p(x)\equiv 1\pmod{(x-2)}$. Now apply the Chinese remainder algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

Let $P_0(x) =x^2, P_1(x)=(x-1)^2, P_2(x)=x-2$.

Let $A_0(x) = 0, A_1(x) = 1+(x-1)=x, A_2(x)=1$.

We want to find $p(x)$ such that  $$p(x) \equiv A_i(x) \pmod{P_i(x)}$$

We let $$Q(x)=x^2(x-1)^2(x-2)$$

Denote $Q_i(x) = \frac{Q(x)}{P_i(x)}.$ We have
$$Q_0(x) =(x-1)^2(x-2)$$
$$Q_1(x) = x^2(x-2)$$
$$Q_2(x)=x^2(x-1)^2$$

Let $$\sum_{i=0}^2S_i(x)Q_i(x) = 1$$

where $degree(S_i)<degree(P_i)$

$$S_0(x)(x-1)^2(x-2)+S_1(x)x^2(x-2)+S_2(x)x^2(x-1)^2=1\tag{1}$$

Let $x=2$, we conclude that $S_2(x) = \frac14$.

Let $x=1$, we have $S_1(1)=-1$. We let $S_1(x)=ax+b$, we have $a+b=-1$.

Differentiating $(1)$ once,

$$\frac{d}{dx}[S_0(x)(x-1)^2(x-2)+S_2(x)x^2(x-1)^2]+\frac{d}{dx}[S_1(x)(x^3-2x^2)]=0$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}[S_0(x)(x-1)^2(x-2)+S_2(x)x^2(x-1)^2]+a(x^3-2x^2)+(ax+b)(3x^2-4x)=0$$

Let $x=1$, we have $-a-(a+b)=0$, that is $b=-2a$. That is $a=1$ and $b=-2$.

$S_1(x)=x-2$.

Now let's compute $A_1(x)S_1(x) \pmod{P_1(x)}$ to reduce the degree:

\begin{align}
A_1(x) S_1(x) &\equiv x(x-2) \pmod{(x-1)^2} \\
&\equiv x^2-2x \pmod{(x-1)^2} \\
&\equiv x^2-2x+1-1 \pmod{(x-1)^2} \\
&\equiv -1 \pmod{(x-1)^2}.
\end{align}

Let $B_i \equiv A_iS_i \pmod{P_i}$,
The desired polynomial is $\sum_{i=0}^2 B_i(x)Q_i(x)$, that is

\begin{align}-Q_1(x)+ \frac14Q_2(x)&=-x^2(x-2)+\frac14x^2(x-1)^2 \\
&=x^2 \left[ -(x-2) + \frac14(x-1)^2\right]\end{align}

Relevant reading from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Existence_(direct_construction))

[image]